# How to change/create the form dynamically upon select

Tags: java, javascript, html, hibernate, jquery-ui

I have a requirement to allow the user to insert the values into the database from the webpage.

First the user selects the table he wants to insert the record into , then depending upon the selected table , a form should be populated with column names and text boxes so that user can enter the data and save.

On page load a drop down box would be shown with all the table names .When user selected the table how to show/create the form depending upon the table user selected ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some server side language for this.If you are familiar with php it will be pretty easy, when user selects table you connect to DB to selected table and in a loop display all fields that you need from selected table. Paste some code and we might be able to help